Can I use Twilio to receive SIPREC from a SBC and act as a SRS that sends events to my webhook
My goal is to receive Twilio events (call start, etc) and a websocket audio stream in my application, of calls that are happening in Avaya. In this particular case, the only way to receive those calls is via SIPREC, as Single Step Conferencing is not available.
Since SIPREC is similar to SIP in protocol, I assumed that a Twilio SIP domain can be used as SRS, that sends the call events to my webhook that I configured in the Twilio SIP domain.
When I setup the Twilio SIP domain as the SRS in the SIPREC configuration, the SIP domain returns the 513 message too large error.
(FYI, to make it slightly more confusing: I am unable to test the actual connection between Avaya SIPREC and Twilio, therefore I set up a separate Twilio Phone Number that sends a SIPREC to the Twilio SIP domain using TwiML and a Stream Connector.)
I am not familiar with the details of the SIP and SIPREC protocol, and I can only find information about actual recording servers online. What I really want is to receive the audio stream in realtime, such that my application can do its thing while the call is happening. We've used Twilio before, and therefore have a complete integration, so this has my preference.
I have spoken to a Twilio Support agent at length, who does not seem to understand my situation completely, as they keep suggesting things that are outside of the possible actions I can take ("use Twilio call recording with recording status callback" (I can not, since the call has not yet reached Twilio...), etc).
I set up SIPREC from a Twilio Call (I know this is confusing, but I just did it to test the flow) instead of Avaya to test if the Twilio SIP domain could handle SIPREC. I did this using a Twilio Stream Connector add-on, that can send SIPREC to a SIP URI. The SIP URI I entered was the one of the Twilio SIP domain I created (I also had to register a user/endpoint, as Twilio Stream Connector requires this).
The SIPREC connection was established, but the SIP domain returns a 513 message too large error. This tells me that it received something it did not expect. I don't know if this is because it is SIPREC instead of SIP, or if this can be another cause.
